# Linux Servers in same network unreachable from each other, but however reachable from outside

Tags: networking, route

I have 5 servers in the same network with IPS X.X.X.110 - 114. They are all connected to a switch. I am able to reach all 5 of them from outside(internet). However, I cant connect from servers 0 - servers 3. From Server 4 however, I can contact all other servers and vice versa.

I checked the route and it seems to be the same on all servers. Here is the entry for it:

```
default         static.x.x.x 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0                                                                                           
x.x.x.96      static.x.x.x 255.255.255.224 UG    0      0        0 eth0                                                                                           
x.x.x.96      *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

All of them are running Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

Comment: Can you please supply the netmasks of each of the servers?

Comment: Are you setup the IP address in same vlan or not?
What the icmp response when you try to ping each other?
Please check your networking setup and ensure that your netmask are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue by issuing the following command:

```
ip route flush cache
```

It appears that the routing table could have been corrupted.